# why using clock() get minus number in measuring CPU time

Tags: c++, clock

I am using clock() to measure the amount of CPU time for my algorithm.

The code is like:

```
start_time = clock();
//code to be timed
.
end_time = clock();
elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time)*1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", elapsed_time/1000, elapsed_time%1000 );
```

But I get "0 seconds -175 milliseconds" as a result. I can't understand why. 
And seems "1 seconds 349 milliseconds" can really take 10 minutes or more in elapse time.
Is that common?

Comment: Are you trying to time a program that fork?

Comment: Yes, that is just what I would like to do.

Comment: Please show us more of the code—with the types of the variables, etc. And make sure that what you show here is exactly the same as what you're compiling and testing (e.g., if you change the printf to use %lld, show that here). And also tell us what platform you're on (and whether you're building for a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture).

Answer (score 1):

Forking is a special case, where this type of code will result in negative time. One of the reason is that, `clock()` will return the number of clock ticks since the start of the program.

Just as a reminder, the value in `start_time` will be copied over to the child process.

- For the parent process, the time should be positive. Since the clock tick count for `start_time` and `end_time` are for the same process.
- For the child process, since it only starts **after** `fork()`, `clock()` will return the number of clock tick that the program runs from this point onwards. The time before the `fork()` is not recorded.

  Since the starting reference for counting clock ticks are different:

  - `start_time` is the number of clock ticks since the start of the **parent** process till the first `clock()`
  - `end_time` is the number of clock ticks since the start of the **child** process till the second `clock()`)

  It may result in negative result. Positive result is also possible, if the child process runs long enough to exceed the amount of time that the parent process starts.

**EDIT**

I am not sure what the expected time is, but if you want to count: clock ticks of parent process from start to end, and clock ticks of child process from after `fork()` to end, then modify your code to overwrite `start_time` with a new value of `clock()` in the child process. Or you can just set `start_time` to 0.

Comment: Hi nhahtdh, I have forbidden multi-thread. So it should not be the fork case, right?

Comment: I don't get it. How long can the program run? And do you spawn thread/processes in between?

Comment: I meant that I have disabled the use of thread pool. It runs for about an hour.

Comment: In this case it is possibly overflow. Can you check the `sizeof` the `clock_t` on the machine that runs the program?

Comment: seems clock_t here is 8bytes.I have removed *1000 and modify elapsed_time to be unsigned long. Do you have other advice?

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea.

Comment: @rei liu: I'm not sure what "forbidden multi-thread" or "disabled the use of thread pool" means, but multithreading has nothing to do with forking (except deep down at the kernel level). The question is whether you're calling fork() between the two calls to clock(). Since your response to the comments on the actual question said "that is just what I would like to do", nhahtdh assumed that that was indeed what you would like to do. If it isn't, just say so.

Answer (score 0):

If start_time and end_time are 32-bit integers, they can only hold about 2147 seconds (about 35 minutes) before rolling over into negative numbers, because CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000000.

But it's worse than that, because you multiply the difference by 1000, which means if it's anything over 2.147 seconds it's going to overflow.

On the other hand, if they're not 32-bit integers, you're using the wrong printf format specifiers (and you're probably getting and ignoring a warning from the compiler), so you're seeing garbage.

Comment: They are both type of "clock_t".Is that going to overflow? Yes, I will try again with "%f". Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, clock_t is unsigned long, meaning your arithmetic will overflow in 32-bit builds, while your printf will print garbage in 64-bit builds. And… I hope this isn't insulting your intelligence, but switching to %f isn't going to help unless you also switch all the variables to doubles.